# How to show Riemann integrability

Tags: integration, riemann-integration

> Is the function $$f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{x^2}{2}+4 &, x\ge0 \\
> \>                      \frac{-x^2}{2}+2   &, x<0.\end{cases}$$ Riemann integrable in the interval$[-1,2]$? Does there exist a function $g$ such that $g'(x)=f(x)$?

I want to know how to show the Riemann integrability of a function . Because this function is discontinuous . And fundamental theorem of calculus say that a function $g(x)$ such that $g'(x) = f(x)$ only when $f(x)$ is continuous.

Could someone explain the link between continuity and Riemann integrability. And post some notes that have example problems on Riemann integrability ?

Comment: To show Riemann integrability, use the construction in the definition.  To get g(x) just integrate.f(x).  What puzzles me is that you need to ask these questions.  What is your math background?

Comment: I am learning real analysis . And I have a bit of trouble to exactly understand which functions are Riemann integrable and which are not.

Comment: @Vinay Varahabhotla As a minimum, bounded functions with at most a finite number of discontinuities are Riemann integrable.  Divide the domain into a finite number of parts where the function is continuous in each part and use the standard construction on each part.

Comment: RRL g′(x) will have a jump at x=0 with right and left derivatives of g(x) equal to the right and left limits at x=0

Comment: @herb steinberg: I realize that. My point is for OP to recognize that $f$ can’t be a derivative $g’$ on the entire interval as a derivative must satisfy the Darboux intermediate value property.  Of course this line is not going anywhere and I deleted the hint.

Comment: So from what I understand , I can integrate $f(x)$ piece wise by dividing it into continuous functions . But there exists no $g(x)$ s.t. $g’(x)=f(x)$

Comment: you are correct, since f(x) is discontinuous at x=0, there is no function with a derivative at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will write a set of criteria to figure out if a given bounded function $f:[a, b] \to\mathbb {R} $ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b] $ in increasing order of conceptual complexity. Let $D$ be the set of points in $[a, b] $ at which $f$ is discontinuous.

The function $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b] $ if

- $f$ is continuous on $[a, b] $. Here $D=\emptyset$.
- $f$ is monotone on $[a, b] $. Here $D$ is either finite or countably infinite.
- $f$ has a finite number of discontinuities ie $D$ is finite.
- $D$ has a finite number of limit/accumulation points.
- **and only if** $D$ is of measure zero.

For your given function you can apply either the second or third criterion and see that the given function is Riemann integrable on $[-1,2]$.

The question of existence of a function $g$ with $g'=f$ is tricky but there are two results which can give definite answers in both directions:

- If $f$ is continuous on $[a, b] $ then there is a function $g$ defined on $[a, b] $ with $g'=f$ and one such function is $g(x) =\int_{a} ^{x} f(t) \, dt$ (via Fundamental Theorem of Calculus).
- If $f$ has a jump discontinuity at some point in $[a, b] $ then no such function $g$ exists (via Darboux theorem).

But note that if the discontinuity of $f$ is not of jump kind then we may have a function $g$ with $g'=f$. An example is $g(x) =x^2\sin(1/x),x\neq 0,g(0)=0$ and $f(x) =2x\sin(1/x)-\cos(1/x),f(0)=0$. We have $g'=f$ on whole of $\mathbb {R} $ but $f$ is discontinuous at $0$ and it is Riemann integrable on any bounded and closed interval.

Comment: Thx very much for this answer

Answer (score 2):

$f$ is increasing on $[-1,2]$, hence $f$ is Riemann - integrable on $[-1,2]$.

There is no function $g$ such that $g$ is differentiable and $g'=f$:

suppose, to the contrary that such a function $g$ exists. Then show that there is a constant $c$ with

$g(x)=\frac{x^3}{6}+4x+c$ if $x \ge 0$ and $g(x)=-\frac{x^3}{6}+2x+c$ if $x<0.$

Then show that

$ \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x-0} \ne \lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x-0},$ a contradiction, since $g$ is differentiable at $x=0.$