# Integration and existence of an antiderivative

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals, riemann-integration

Let $ f: \mathbb {R} \rightarrow {\mathbb {R}} $ be given by

$$ f (x) = \left \{\begin {matrix}
\sin ({\frac {1} {x}}), & \text {if} \phantom {a} x \neq 0; \\
 c, & \text {if} \phantom {a} x = 0
\end {matrix} \right. $$
where $ c \in [-1,1]$. For what values ​​of $c$ is there an antiderivative of $f$?

I do not know of a theorem of the form "if and only if" that  it tells me when a function $ f $ has no antiderivative.

Anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: See this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2603106/72031 and then you will find that $c=0$ fits the bill here. Try to have a look at derivative of $g(x) =x^2\cos(1/x), g(0)=0$.

Comment: Also see this answer for two definite results on existence of anti-derivatives : https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3120054/72031

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Your argument contradicts Lebesgue's theorem, right? Because this function is discontinuous for every point $ c \in [-1,1] $. Then by Lebesgue's theorem I can conclude that this function is not Riemann-integrable, right?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Is it easy to see that the function $ f $ is discontinuous for any point $ c \in [-1,1] $?

Comment: Perhaps you are confused. The function in your question is discontinuous at single point $0$ no matter what value of $c$ is chosen. Thus it is Riemann integrable. A surprise is that the integral function $F$ given in zhw's answer is differentiable at $0$ making it an anti-derivative of your $f$ if $c=0$.

Comment: Also you do not need Lebesgue theorem here. Don't use a canon to kill a fly.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh the integral function F given in zhw's answer is differentiable at 0 making...Is that easy to see? I tried by definition, but I do not know what to do with that integral?

Comment: You should read my first two comments carefully. The fact that $F$ is differentiable at $0$ is not obvious, but you should see the linked answer in my comment which deals with a similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Define $F(x) = \int_0^x \sin (1/t)\, dt.$ Then $F'(x) = \sin(1/x),$ $x\ne 0.$ Does $F'(0)$ exist?

Comment: Is that easy to see? I tried by definition, but I do not know what to do with that integral?

Comment: Deleted by previous comment as it may be easier to write the integrand as  $\sin(1/t)(-1/t^2)(-t^2)$ and integrating by parts.

Comment: Are you sure about that?The result is $$f(0)=F'(0)=\lim_{x\rightarrow{0}}{\frac{F(x)-F(0)}{x}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow{0}}{\frac{F(x)}{x}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow{0}}{\frac{x^{2}\cos{\frac{1}{x}-\int_{0}^{x}{2t\cos{\frac{1}{t}}dt}}}{x}}=0?$$ right?

Comment: Note the last expression $\to 0.$

Comment: It's clear that $x\cos\frac{1}{x}\rightarrow{0}$, when $x\rightarrow{0}$, but $\frac{-\int_{0}^{x}{2t\cos{\frac{1}{t}}dt}}{x}\rightarrow{0}$, when $x\rightarrow{0}$. Why?

Comment: In absolute value, the top is $\le \int_0^x2t\,dt.$

Comment: Note that $\frac{-\int_{0}^{x}{2t\cos{\frac{1}{t}}dt}}{x}\leq \frac{\int_{0}^{x}{2tdt}}{x}=x\rightarrow{0}$, when $x\rightarrow{0}$. right?

Comment: Yes, although you want absolute values on the first expression.

Comment: What can happen when $c \neq 0$? That $ F $ still works?

Comment: Suppose $G$ is an antiderivative with $G'(0)=c.$ Then $(G-F)' = 0$ on $(0,\infty).$ Thus $G-F$ is constant on $(0,\infty),$ hence on $[0,\infty).$ Thus $(G-F)'(c) = 0=G'(0) = c.$